# How to use reflection to assign values to unknown structures

Tags: go, reflect

Structs may contains float32, int32, string or pointer to struct.
Here is my code. But i do not know how to assign values to the structs inside.

```
type T struct {
    A int
    B string
    C *P
}

type P struct {
    A string
    B int
}

func main() {
    t := T{}
    decode(&t, []string{"99", "abc", "abc", "99"})
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
func decode(a interface{}, val []string) {
    rdecode(reflect.ValueOf(a).Elem(), val)
}

func rdecode(rv reflect.Value, val []string) int {
    var index int
    for i := 0; i < rv.NumField(); i++ {
        f := rv.Field(i)

        if f.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
            if f.IsNil() {
                f.Set(reflect.New(f.Type().Elem()))
            }
            f = f.Elem()
        }

        switch f.Kind() {
        case reflect.Int:
            tmp, _ := strconv.Atoi(val[index])
            f.Set(reflect.ValueOf(tmp))
            index++
        case reflect.String:
            f.SetString(val[index])
            index++
        case reflect.Struct:
            index += rdecode(f, val[index:])
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    return index
}
```

https://play.golang.com/p/Jyj0flzDBhu

Comment: And how about the pointer to the struct like the updated content above? Thanks again.

Comment: @ray you can add a new `case reflect.Ptr` to the switch, and inside use `f.Elem()` to dereference the pointer, check the dereferenced value's type and if struct descend. Note that if that pointer field is not initialized upfront that code will panic, you either need to initialize it upfront, or you can use `reflect.New`.

Comment: I have tried lots of times, but failed. Here is my wrong code, could you tell me how to correct the code? Thanks.
```
case reflect.Ptr:
   a := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(f.Elem()))
   f := a.Elem()
   if f.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
    index += rdecode(f, val[index:])
   }
```

Comment: @ray I've updated the answer to include the handling of pointers.